# Using Count giving wrong number of rows

Tags: php, sql

Before I was using this code to count rows

```
echo $db_handle->numRows("SELECT * FROM orders WHERE DATE(reattemptdate) = CURDATE()");
```

than i found it effects on **performance**, than i tried to use below code, but it not giving correct number of rows, what wrong i done in below code ?

```
$sqldelivery = "SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM orders  WHERE DATE(reattemptdate) = CURDATE()";
$resultdeliverys = $db_handle->runSelectQuery($sqldelivery); 
$numrowsresultdelivery =count($resultdeliverys);         
echo $numrowsresultdelivery;
```

**Database connection code** :

```
function numRows($query) {
        $result  = mysqli_query($this->conn,$query);
        $rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        return $rowcount;
    }
```

Comment: It lacks a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second code, the query will always return 1 row - a row with the column `count` being the number of rows, so...

```
$numrowsresultdelivery =count($resultdeliverys);
```

Will probably always be 1, you need something like...

```
$numrowsresultdelivery =$resultdeliverys[0]['count'];
```

to extract the `count` field from the first row of the result.
(Note I don't know if this is the right notation, but it's the principle of needing a field from the result rather than the number of results.)

Answer (score 1):

You must already have the count number via `$resultdeliverys->count`.

```
$sqldelivery = "SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM orders  WHERE DATE(reattemptdate) = CURDATE()";
$resultdeliverys = $db_handle->runSelectQuery($sqldelivery); 

// Try this to know if it's returning array or object
var_dump($resultdeliverys);
```